# Font size (and not only) changing size after reloading page

Tags: html, css

I'm working for the first time with a new CMS (Anchor CMS) and I started to code my custom theme, however I have a problem:

When I load the page for the first time it is usually wrong, some parts of the layout are a bit moved and some font sizer are just incorrect, for example I have this:

[image: Wrong]

And when I click **inspect element** to see what's going on or **refresh** the page it corrects automatically:

[image: Correct]

If I keep refreshing sometimes it is correct and sometimes not. This is the first time that I encounter a similar behavior, what could be the cause of this? It just makes no sense to me.

### EDIT:

This time I had been able to use 'inspect element' when the page was wrong without being automatically corrected, here is an image o what is happening:
[image: 23px?]

Where does the 23px comes from?

### EDIT2:

I just seen the "small" attribute, I didn't realized it was there, removed it but it does **not** solve the problem.

Comment: Caching problem – browser still showing “old” styles occasionally? If that’s not it – then make sure your HTML and CSS is valid first of all – because when relying on the browser’s error correction, (nearly) _everything_ can happen.

Comment: @CBroe I just checked both CSS and HTML and they resulted valid, I tried also on Opera (before it was with Chrome) and the issue happened randomly also there (like every 20-30 page refresh).

Comment: Where and how are you loading those fonts from? Also, just curious, what happens when you zoom in and out the page when it loads badly (by doing `ctrl+` and `ctrl-`)? Does that fix the layout?

Comment: @Shomz I'm not loading the fonts from the site and yes, when I do zoom in/out it does fix the layout.

Comment: And other browsers? This is something I noticed in Chrome, it usually happens when I set the Chrome font settings to custom.

Comment: @Shomz it looks like it does happen only on webkit browsers.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. And can you show how are you loading the fonts (parts of the HEAD where you load fonts and the css; and also the css part)?

Comment: @Shomz I'm not loading the fonts from the website, they just are on my pc.

Comment: That's fine, but how did you define them?

Comment: @Shomz normally, just like this: http://pastebin.com/jJ4gwcYk